# ui bootstrap datepicker not taking js Date() object as string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-filters

I am using [ui bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup) in my project, when i am getting data from database the type of this date value `Thu Aug 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` is `string` when i am using

`new Date('Thu Aug 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');`

Then it is working properly, i don't want to convert it in `controller` using `new Date();`, i actually want to achieve this conversion using `directive` or `filter` how can i achieve this? my datepicker field is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control custom-form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="moduleName.main.expiryDate" is-open="expiryDateCal.opened" datepicker-options="expiryDateOptions" name="expiryDate" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
```

Comment: you can write a `filter` and append it to the `ng-model` which will return date object just add the `new Date('Thu Aug 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');` in your filter

Comment: i like this idea and i am agree with you but i don't know how to append a `filter` to `ng-model` this is my only problem.

Comment: added answer with usage of directive instead of filter as you are using datepicker which requires ng-model to play with where directive gives you more advantage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using filter is not a good idea in the case of with `ng-model`.So instead I've created a directive which converts the string date to Date object.

Run the code sample to check the working.Hope this helps,you just need to add `date` attribute to the HTML tags with ng-model as required.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl',function($scope,$filter){
  
  $scope.date="Thu Aug 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
   
  });

app.directive('date', function(dateFilter) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from view format to model format
        return new Date(data); //converted
      });

      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
        //convert data from model format to view format
        return new Date(data); //converted
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" class="widget-content" ng-controller="Ctrl">

  <input type="text" ng-model="date" date/>
  </div>
```